# drupal_add_css not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I need to use [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_css/6) to call stylesheets onto single Drupal 6 pages. I don't want to edit the main theme stylesheet as there will be a set of individual pages which all need completely new styles - the main sheet would be massive if i put it all in there.

My solution was to edit the page in PHP editor mode and do this:

```
<?php 
drupal_add_css("/styles/file1.css", "theme");
?>

<div id="newPageContent">stuff here in html</div>
```

But when I view source, there is nothing there! Not even a broken CSS link or anything, it's just refusing to add the CSS sheet to the CSS package put into the page head.

Variations don't seem to work either:

```
drupal_add_css($path = '/styles/file1.css', $type = 'module', $media = 'all', $preprocess = TRUE)
```

My template header looks like this, I've not changed anything from the default other than adding a custom JavaScript.

```
<head>
    <?php print $head ?>
    <title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
    <?php print $styles ?>
    <?php print $scripts ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print base_path() ?>misc/askme.js"></script>    
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <?php print phptemplate_get_ie_styles(); ?>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Why is this function not working?

Comment: If you did have it working, have your caching settings changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was very much to use the [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module - great little addon!

Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Allows administrators to inject CSS into the page output based on configurable rules. It's useful for adding simple CSS tweaks without modifying a site's official theme. The CSS is added using Drupal's standard drupal_add_css() function and respects page caching, etc. The 2.x brach leverages CTools so CSS can be included with Feature changes (ie. CSS that improves the look of a View can be packaged with the View).

Answer (score 7):

It is not quite clear where you are selecting the template that you have in your example. If you are selecting it from a module then you can just use drupal_add_css in the module rather than the template.

If you have your own theme you can use [template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_page/6) and put logic in there to add the relevant CSS (you can also use it to select the template to use).

Comment: Hiya, I'm really sorry but I absolutely did have this working straight from a page the other week. I thought "oh great thats easy" and built the rest of my site. Now I go back to implement it and it's not working. Typical :P

Comment: Another note to this, if you use template_preprocess_page with drupal_add_css() make sure  you add force it into the styles array like so:
`drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). "/css/page.css", "theme");  
 $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();`

Answer (score 6):

I have noticed something weird and it might fix your problem:

```
drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('theme','themname') . '/working.css','module' ,'all' , false );

drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('theme','themname') . '/path/to/folder/notworking.css','module' ,'all' , false );
```

The first one will work ebcause the style it in the main them folder
The second line will not work because the style is in a sub folder !

Edit:

i think it did not work because  i did not write the path the the style file properly :S so please disregard my answer

```
drupal_add_css( drupal_get_path('theme','test') . '/pages/subpage/style.css','theme');
```

is working

Answer (score 4):

This function wont work in templates. The reason is that the variable $styles which will hold all the stylesheet html will already have been generated at this point, so drupal_add_css wont work as it adds to that. if you want to do this in your theme, you would probably have to add the css file manually

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ... />
```

The other way would be to use drupal_add_css in a module, but you might have a hard time adding the correct css files on the pages you want.

Comment: really? I had this working a week ago on another site :o - I'd edited drupal_add_css into a page in PHP mode.

Comment: I think you are right as to why the function won't work but wrong that it can't be done in the theming layer. See my answer.

Comment: @Jeremy I was a bit uncertain if you could or couldn't get it to work that way, that's why I said probably. But using preprocess_page wont help much if you want to do it per page. You might as well do it in a module then.

Comment: I would add that the function can be made to work in _some_ templates and preprocess functions. What it won't work in is the page.tpl.php or hook_preprocess_page, because by then you're too late: the $styles variable has already been compiled by phptemplate_preprocess_page() (NB D6 terminology; D7, probably html.tpl.php and phptemplate_preprocess_html().)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use drupal_add_css() inside your template.php file; [this page](http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/6080) has a good example of how to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the link, wyrmmage. That's very useful. I think the rest of the code in the page is unneccessary. You probably just need these since drupal 6 already automatically check for file existence:

```
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/yourcss.css', 'theme');
// Add the following to regenerate $styles. 
// This is needed for template_preprocess_page() since css is already generated at this point.
$variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code inside template.php works for me:

```
function alagna_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/header_1.css', 'theme');
        $vars['css'] = drupal_add_css();
        $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
}
```

explained:

1. alagna is the theme name
2. header_1.css is the css file required.

Answer (score 1):

drupal_add_css is expecting a path relative to base path whereas drupal_get_path does not return the path relative to base path.

`global $base_path; 

drupal_add_css($base_path . drupal_get_path('module / theme','name') . "/styles/file1.css", "module / theme");`

You can choose between module and theme accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[common.inc drupal_get_css($css = NULL)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_css/6)

**Parameters**

**$css: (optional) An array of CSS files.** If no array is provided, the default stylesheets array is used instead.

```
    $css    =   $vars['css'];
// unset the system css files
$unset_css = array
    'modules/system/system.css',
    'modules/system/system-menus.css',
);

foreach($unset_css as $css_f) {
    if(isset($css['all']['module'][$css_f])) {
        unset($css['all']['module'][$css_f]);
    }
}

// add css
$css['all']['theme'][drupal_get_path('theme', 'openpublish_theme') . '/css/style.css'] = true;
$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
```